# Using LLVM Libraries in C++ Project

Tags: clang, llvm

I'm currently having problem with simple project(or llvm-example for that matter). My assignment requires me to use llvm libraries, however this isn't as easy as I had hoped.

I've build `LLVM` using `MinGW GCC` and `CMake`. After build I can compile with clang fine. However if I create simple hello world type of program

```
#include "llvm-c/Core.h"

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
  return 0;
}
```

and try to compile it with

```
clang++ main.cpp
```

I get

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
./llvm-c/Core.h:18:10: fatal error: 'llvm-c/ErrorHandling.h' file not found
#include "llvm-c/ErrorHandling.h"
```

For this example I have copied contents of `include` directory into directory with `main.cpp`. After getting this issue I tried to inspect those headers and all of them have position `llvm/` or `llvm-c/`, instead of pure relative address. I figured these libs were used to build/make llvm and libs for me to use are actually in `build` directory, which is where I have built llvm, but `include` directory in build has only about 1/2 `*.h` files.

I can't seem to find anything in documentation related to this and even basic llvm examples are expecting to include libs in format like `llvm/Core.h`

**EDIT**

After solving inclusion problem, now I get several other problems which seems to be linked to mingw.

This is how new program looks.

```
#define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS

#include <llvm-c/Core.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    LLVMModuleRef rff =  LLVMModuleCreateWithName("testname");
    return 0;
}
```

this generates

```
d:\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\..\..\..\libLLVMSupport.a(CommandLine.cpp.obj):CommandLine.cpp|| undefined reference to `__mingw_strtod'|
d:\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\..\..\..\libLLVMSupport.a(regerror.c.obj):regerror.c|| undefined reference to `__ms_vsnprintf'|
d:\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\..\..\..\libLLVMSupport.a(Path.cpp.obj):Path.cpp|| undefined reference to `SHGetKnownFolderPath@16'|
d:\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\..\..\..\libLLVMSupport.a(Path.cpp.obj):Path.cpp|| undefined reference to `_imp__CoTaskMemFree@4'|
d:\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\..\..\..\libLLVMSupport.a(Path.cpp.obj):Path.cpp|| undefined reference to `_imp___chsize_s'|
d:\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\..\..\..\libLLVMSupport.a(Path.cpp.obj):Path.cpp|| undefined reference to `FOLDERID_LocalAppData'|
d:\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\..\..\..\libLLVMSupport.a(Path.cpp.obj):Path.cpp|| undefined reference to `FOLDERID_LocalAppData'|
d:\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\..\..\..\libLLVMSupport.a(Path.cpp.obj):Path.cpp|| undefined reference to `FOLDERID_LocalAppData'|
d:\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\..\..\..\libLLVMSupport.a(Path.cpp.obj):Path.cpp|| undefined reference to `FOLDERID_LocalAppData'|
d:\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\..\..\..\libLLVMSupport.a(Path.cpp.obj):Path.cpp|| undefined reference to `FOLDERID_Profile'|
d:\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\..\..\..\libLLVMSupport.a(Path.cpp.obj):Path.cpp|| undefined reference to `FOLDERID_Profile'|
d:\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\..\..\..\libLLVMSupport.a(Path.cpp.obj):Path.cpp|| undefined reference to `FOLDERID_Profile'|
d:\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\..\..\..\libLLVMSupport.a(Path.cpp.obj):Path.cpp|| undefined reference to `FOLDERID_Profile'|
d:\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\..\..\..\libLLVMSupport.a(Path.cpp.obj):Path.cpp|| undefined reference to `FOLDERID_LocalAppData'|
d:\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\..\..\..\libLLVMSupport.a(Path.cpp.obj):Path.cpp|| undefined reference to `FOLDERID_LocalAppData'|
d:\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\..\..\..\libLLVMSupport.a(Path.cpp.obj):Path.cpp|| undefined reference to `FOLDERID_LocalAppData'|
d:\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\..\..\..\libLLVMSupport.a(Path.cpp.obj):Path.cpp|| undefined reference to `FOLDERID_LocalAppData'|
d:\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\..\..\..\libLLVMSupport.a(TimeValue.cpp.obj):TimeValue.cpp|| undefined reference to `_localtime32'|
```

I used `llvm-config --libs core` for linker additions.

Tried commands:

```
g++ main.cpp -lLLVMCore -lLLVMSupport
clang++ main.cpp -lLLVMCore -lLLVMSupport
```

Comment: "For this example I have copied contents of include directory into directory with main.cpp" - Do you mean that "fixed" your issue?

Comment: In build system you should provide the include path with the llvm/include directory and library path with the directory in build where you have your library binaries... presumably build/lib

Comment: No it didnt. It wont compile at this point, because libs are included with their folders in path(which makes final path something like `llvm-c/llvm-c/Core.h` I figured that maybe removing folder from each instance of `#include` would help, but its too much files and I dont think this is right approach.

Comment: As for paths, llvm libs that have been build are in `PATH` so there shouldn't be this problem, and static link problem would pop different error. I did try to add include path to compilation `-I"path/to/include"`, but this case builds first `*.h` and fails at the second one (one inside that header)

Comment: "and even basic llvm examples are expecting to include libs in format like llvm/Core.h" - so do you mean that the only problem remains is about that quoted sentence? Where do you get those examples?

Comment: I can't say this is the only problem. However static lib error pops only after being required in `*.h` files, so unless I somehow solve this `include` issue I cant focus on the next one.

Comment: Actually, if you just copied the contents of the include directory, you would get the issue you mentioned. Instead if you just have the -I option properly set then the files would be found and the relative paths inside the headers would work even though the files are in the same folder...

Answer (score 3):

Those are WinAPI references. The easiest way is to find those are google for documentation for it or go to the mingw library directory ( `..\mingw530_32\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\` ) and find in files.

So

- `FOLDERID_LocalAppData` is defined in `libuuid.a` so use the `-luuid` compile parameter
- `_imp__CoTaskMemFree@4` is defined in `libole32.a` so use the `-lole32` compile parameter

For me `g++ -std=c++11 -ID:\Devel\install\include main.cc -LD:\Devel\install\lib -lLLVMCore -lLLVMSupport -luuid -lole32`

is working as I installed the llvm to `D:\Devel\install`

Answer (score 0):

If you need the headers from your-llvm/include directory instead of copying the contents of the include directory you should just specify the include path to your-llvm/include with -I option or whatever the build system requires.

Comment: Already tried that, before posting this question. `clang++ main.cpp -I"D:\llvm\include"` here is command I used. And this is result: `In file included from D:\llvm\include/llvm-c/ErrorHandling.h:17:0,
                 from D:\llvm\include/llvm-c/Core.h:18,
                 from main.cpp:1:
D:\llvm\include/llvm-c/Types.h:17:36: fatal error: llvm/Support/DataTypes.h: No
such file or directory
 #include "llvm/Support/DataTypes.h"
                                    ^
compilation terminated.`

Comment: I have finally got this working, its mostly that, however what was needed to be done is to add not only include directory of `llvm/include` but also `llvm/build/include`. Build seems to have generated few libs on its own. Now its just pops "undefined referce to ..." errors which I will add to main question.